# mongodb custom objectId depending on object type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, objectid

my question:
I am building a project with mongoDB/mongoose, I have different Schemas Users - Locations - Devices etc.

I am using the Object Id's generated by mongo to have unique links that are going to be sharable.

I still want mongo to generate the Id's and index them, but i want to add 2 characters to them for example: users ---> U-573c5f2dc8973c3cee73f0ae, Locations L-573c5f2dc8973c3cee73f0ae, and so on...

I will appreciate if somebody can help me out with this.

Comment: Object Id has to be of length 24 characters. It will be invalid if you try to add or delete characters from it.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Users will be in this own collection anyway, so what's the benefit?

Comment: I am applying a filter in the front end, that uses the Id on each object, I guess I wil have to figure out a different way